# why is slice() altering the state when used in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function, lists=[] at start:

```
handleAddList(s) {

   var temp = this.state.lists.slice();
   temp.push(s);
   console.log(temp);
   this.setState({lists: temp},console.log(this.state.lists) ); 
}
```

why does the first console.log return the value of s but the second console.log returns []?

also, why if i remove slice() do both console.logs now show the value of s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second console log returns `[]` because it hasn't been set yet because calls to setState are async.

When you remove `.slice()` you are creating a reference to `this.state.lists` and mutating it directly which is not async so it happens immediately. However, mutating state directly should never be done.

Instead, keep using `.slice()` to clone your state, then mutate the clone and setState as needed. When you need to view state you should use [react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools).

Comment: ...but the second console.log is in a call back function.  shouldn't that update the state?

Comment: see Konrads comment